# How to set ItemsSource for a databinding from the code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

I cannot figure out how to set ItemsSource to my Pivot programatically. I am using MVVM Light ViewModelLocator where my ViewModel is registered. Then I set the DataSource of my Page and in the xaml of the Pivot I set its ItemsSource. But in the ViewModel I have other collection that I want to change at runtime to be an ItemsSource for my Pivot:

Here is my ViewModelLocator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TripTypeViewModel>();
    }

    public TripTypeViewModel TripTypeVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TripTypeViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup() {}
}
```

XAML of the page:

```
<Page
...
DataContext = "{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=TripTypeVM }">

...

<Pivot x:Name="TripsSegmentsPivot" Title="Locator" Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TripTypeTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding TripTypeViewModelDataSource}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

So in the ViewModel except TripTypeViewModelDataSource i have also TripTypeViewModelDataSource2.

In the xaml.cs of the View I would usually do this:

```
TripsSegmentsPivot.ItemsSource = ViewModelLocator.TripTypeVM.TripTypeViewModelDataSource;
TripsSegmentsPivot.ItemsSource = ViewModelLocator.TripTypeVM.TripTypeViewModelDataSource2;
```

but its not working..

Comment: The realisation that trying to *set* a UI/view property directly within the VM is definitely not MVVM should guide you to a different approach. As one of the answers says, what you want to do is define the `ItemsSource` as being bound to a VM collection property. You can then freely change that VM property within your VM without having to get down and dirty with specific UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to bind but let's discuss a few...

1. Directly to the Pivot object itself:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.105).aspx

   ```
   MyPivot.Itemsource=mycollection;
   ```
2. You could use a collection view source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx  Visual Stuidio will create these if you drag a container control onto the surface, it also put code in the code behind so you can "wire-it-up" It works very nicely with any collection type and fully integrates with LINQ.
3. You can set up observable collection in the View Model and Bind to them from the view.  The easiest way to do this is to create a Static Instance of the View Model in the View XAML itself because visual studio property page will "See" the view model and allow you to pick the property as an item source.  All you need to do is implement INPC or create a Dependency Property (where needed) and you are all set to go.  You need this to notify the view when a property changes. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=using%20inotifypropertychanged

If you need to change collections at run time, the CollectionViewSource is dead-simple to use.. like this...

```
MyCollectionViewSource.Source = MyCollection.Where(p=>p.Name==SelectedName).ToList(); 
MyCollectionViewSource.Source = MyCollection.Where(p=>p.ID > 500).ToList();
MyCollectionViewSource.Source = MyOtherCollection.ToList();
MyCollectionViewSource.Source = JustSayNoToObamaCare();
```

In the current code it shows:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TripTypeViewModelDataSource}"
```

If you use a CollectionViewSource like this:
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCVS}"

You can then change the collection at will in the viewmodel like this.

```
MyCVS.Source = Collection1;
MyCVS.Source = Collection2;
```

Comment: But i still dont get it how to get to these collections that are inside my ViewModel to do this "MyPivot.Itemsource=mycollection;". They are not static properties..

Comment: The viewmodel only contains the collection which should be a public property with getter setters.  The binding is done either in the xaml or in the VM as a separate concern.

Comment: Don't go after the MyPivot.Itemsource property, go for the VM.TripTypeViewModelDataSource property.  Get the instance of VM and set the collection.

Comment: I got it I have to change the content of the collection in the ViewModel to which my Pivots itemsource is bound. But how to change it when I want to fill it with elements of another type (its ObservableCollection)?

Comment: For binding to other types, you need 2 ObservableCollections of each type (unless you are talking about super-types and sub-types = inheritance).  But when you need to switch types that the view is bound the VM simply...does this : MyPivot.Itemsources = Collection1; or Collection2 depending on the need.

Comment: But I understand that MyPivot.ItemsSource needs to be bound to a collection property inside the VM and thats it. Dealing with the UI control is not very MVVM approach i think

Comment: You don't understand what I'm saying...  The view binds to the VM.  The Pivot control binds from the view to the collection. Only the collection is altered in the view model.  It you don't want to change the anything specific to the Pivot in the ViewModel then you should use the CollectionViewSource in the VM and only bind to that from the View.  That way you simply set the CollectionViewSource.Source property to whatever collection you want. The view has no knowledge of anything but the CollectionViewSource which never changes the binding...

Comment: Try this create a new project, and Drag the Pivot control onto any surface.  Visual Studio should create a CollectionViewSource for you automatically!  All you need to do is follow the instructions it creates for you in the code behind.  You can then move that CVS to the viewmodel and you are all set. Or simply create an event handler to the viewmodel when the CVS.Source has new data...